# Contents of analysis before writing an application

Tags: uml, methodology, analysis

What would be the typical content of an analysis made before development actually starts and what are the different steps taken during a software project? I'm asking because I'd like to do an exhaustive end-of-studies work so this becomes second nature. Any links related to the topic are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the methodology used.
Usually is:
1) Requirements collection
2) Specifications to enforce requirements
3) High-level design according to specifications
4) Implementation according to specifications and original design
5) Unit testing (if applied)
6) Integration testing
7) Verification that all requirements are met
9) Release
This is a waterfall approach. Each stage follows the next in a linear fashion.
You could follow an agile approach, where you use iteration in each phase.
E.g. in step (4) part of the system is implemented and demonstrated and tested. If all is ok, continue implementation of other parts.
This is to ensure that if a requirement has been misunderstood or missing, the whole system would not have to be designed from the start.
Read on waterfall and agile metholodologies.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, software life-cycle is the following: idea->marketing/business_requirement->specification->design->implementation/testing/docs -> success/failure.

#### Update:

typical analysis checks use-cases coverage and time/features trade-offs.

Answer (score 1):

There are different methodologies of developing software called *[software development processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process)*. Take a look at one of them - [Rational Unified Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Unified_Process) (RUP).